# Low ROC AUC with good Information Value

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression

I'm trying to build my first application scorecard with `Logistic Regression` and getting low `ROC AUC score` (about 0.7).
Dataset is about 25'000 rows with 10% of event-rate.

My steps:

1. Filling missing and rare values.
2. WOE binning.
3. Calculating Information Value and deleting low IV (<0.1) variables.
   *Remaining variables IV values  0.107, 0.112, 0.116, 0.164, 0.191, 0.265, 0.288, 0.321, 0.386, 0.388,
   0.457)*
4. Removing highly-correlated variables with 0.9 cut-off. (One var with lower IV was deleted)
5. Training model:

```
param_grid = {'penalty': ['l2'], 'C': 10.0 ** arange(-5, 6)}
estimator = LogisticRegression()
search = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid)
s_train = search.fit(X_train,y_train)
s_train.best_score_
```

*Getting Accuracy  = 0.87*

```
estimator = s_train.best_estimator_
estimator.coef_
pairs = list(zip(X.columns, estimator.coef_[0]))
pairs = sorted(pairs, key = lambda p: abs(p[1]))
pairs = pd.DataFrame(pairs)
pairs = pairs.rename(columns={0: 'VAR', 1 : "Coef_LR"})
coefs = pairs.sort_values(by = 'VAR')
intercept = estimator.intercept_
search.best_score_,coefs, intercept
```

*Getting coefs (0.00215, 0.00257, 0.00281, 0.00318, 0.00399, 0.00553, 0.006, 0.00757, 0.0084, 0.01051)
and -0.03119 Intercept*

ROC AUC and Gini:

```
y_pred_proba = estimator.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test,  y_pred_proba)
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)
gini =  (auc-0.5)/0.5
print(('AUC = {}').format(round(auc,3)))
print(('Gini = {}').format(round(gini,3)))
```

The results is always about 'ROC AUC'=  0.7. I'm trying to get at least 0.8.

What should I pay attention to?